# Python Code for text detection in video not working?

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0

I have this code for text detection in video and it's giving this error every time I try to run it.

Here is my Code :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
#from pytesser import *

def text_detection():
   cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    while True:
        ret,img=cap.read()
        gray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        ret1,mask= cv2.threshold(gray,180,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
        image_final=cv2.bitwise_and(gray,gray,mask=mask)
        ret2,new_img= cv2.threshold(image_final,180,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
        kernel=cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS,(3,3))
        dilated=cv2.dilate(new_img,kernel,iterations=9)
        idk,contours,hierarchy=cv2.findContours(dilated,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
        for contour in contours:
            [x,y,w,h]=cv2. boundingRect(contour)

            if w<35 and h<35:
                continue

         cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,255),2)

         cv2.imshow('text_detect',img)
         k=cv2.waitKey(1)& 0xff
         if k==ord('q'):
            break
         cap.release()
         cv2.destroyAllWindows()



text_detection()
```

Error:

> gray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
>        cv2.error: D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv-3.1.0\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:7456:
>   error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cv::ipp_cvtColor

Please Help me out in this.

Comment: Did you check if `img` is not `None` before it's used in cv2.cvtColor()?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to open() the cam.

```
import cv2

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cam.open(0)
results = [ cam.read()[0] for i in range(100) ]
print results
```

this code snippet should setup, open and verify that the capture is working for a 100 captures.

Comment: Vtik i tried adding the snippet to the code but if you put the snippet in the loop it leads to lot of flickering windows that's ok but when you don't put it in the loop it gives back the same error

Comment: Just add cap.open(0) just before the while loop, not all the snippet. That was just a demo...

Comment: Did you try the snippet alone, it looks like you are not getting the images from the camera. Check that.

Comment: Vtik I already some old scripts which work perfectly fie without cap.open(0) the easily get windows but I don't know what happened with this. I tried your snippet alone once too it shows all the results as true.

Comment: When you added .open(), did you have the same error ?

Comment: Yes that has been happening since then it just open's the window which later on crashes and the error comes back

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no frame captured before converting it to Gray scale.
You should add a check to verify whether frame has been captured or not before processing it further

```
import time

def text_detection():
   cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    while True:
        ret,img=cap.read()

        """ adding 0.5 sec delay and verifying if the frame is captured or not.
            It will print the message if the frame is not captured. """

        time.sleep(0.5)
        if not ret:
           print('No frame is captured')
           break

        gray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        ret1,mask= cv2.threshold(gray,180,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

""" 
perform your normal processing

"""
```